# angular reactive form conditionally validate fields based on another field's value

Tags: angular, angular-reactive-forms, angular-validation

This is my code

```
detailsGroup = new FormGroup({
    userId:new FormControl('1'),
    firstName: new FormControl('', Validators.required),
    lastName: new FormControl('', Validators.required),
    email: new FormControl('',[ Validators.required, Validators.email]),
  });
```

I want if the `userId equal to 1` then the firstname last name and email does not required
`otherwise` those 3 fields change to required and the email also validate the email adress.

Thanks

Comment: You should write a custom Validator

Answer (score 5):

You should write a custom validator, something like this:
Demo: https://angular-custom-validator-p2u1jv.stackblitz.io

```
function nameValidator(form: FormGroup): ValidatorFn {
  return (control: AbstractControl): ValidationErrors | null => {
    const needRequire = form.get('userId').value != 1
    const noValue = needRequire ? !(control.value) : false
    return noValue ? {required: control.value} : null;
  };
}
this.form = new FormGroup({
  userId:new FormControl('1'),
  firstName: new FormControl(''),
  lastName: new FormControl(''),
  email: new FormControl('',[ Validators.required, Validators.email]),
});

this.form.get('firstName').setValidators(nameValidator(this.form))
this.form.get('lastName').setValidators(nameValidator(this.form))
```

Answer (score 3):

In order to achieve this you can use the `setValidators` and `clearValidtors` methods available with the [`FormControl` class](https://angular.io/api/forms/FormControl). Below is how you can use them to dynamically add or remove validators from a particular control of the form. Also the `setValidators` method takes either a single validator or an array of validators as parameters, so in case of email you can use it like this

```
this.detailsForm.get('email').setValidators([Validators.required,Validators.email]);
```

Since angular provides both the required and the email validators, you won't have to write any custom validator functions.

```
import { Component, OnInit, VERSION } from '@angular/core';
import { FormBuilder, FormGroup, Validators } from '@angular/forms';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css'],
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
  name = 'Angular ' + VERSION.major;
  detailsForm: FormGroup;
  validation: boolean;
  constructor(private formBuilder: FormBuilder) {}

  ngOnInit() {
    this.detailsForm = this.formBuilder.group({
      userId: ['', [Validators.required]],
      firstName: ['', [Validators.required]],
      lastName: ['', [Validators.required]],
      email: ['', [Validators.required]],
    });
    this.detailsForm.get('userId').valueChanges.subscribe(() => {
      const val = this.detailsForm.getRawValue();
      if (val.userId.toString() === '1') {
        Object.keys(this.detailsForm.controls).forEach((controlName) => {
          this.detailsForm.controls[controlName].clearValidators();
          this.detailsForm.controls[controlName].updateValueAndValidity();
        });
      } else {
        Object.keys(this.detailsForm.controls).forEach((controlName) => {
          this.detailsForm.controls[controlName].setValidators(
            Validators.required
          );
          this.detailsForm.controls[controlName].updateValueAndValidity();
        });
      }
      this.validation = this.detailsForm.get('email').valid;
    });
  }
}
```

Here is a  [working demo](https://angular-ivy-92h4id.stackblitz.io) of the same. If you type 1 email has no validators and is found valid. If you type any other value the email control becomes invalid.

You can play with the above [editable code here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-92h4id?file=src/app/app.component.ts)

Answer (score 0):

I'm just going to share my sample code which tends to demonstrate how we apply validation for a form filed based on another filed value, in this sample I'm going to apply a validator for sectorId, if doesContainDemo filed value being true.

```
 private _buildForm(): void {
    this.storeForm = this._fb.group({
      name: [
        '',
        Validators.compose([
          Validators.required,
          Validators.minLength(3)
        ])
      ],
      doesContainDemo: [true],
      sectorId: ['', this._sectorValidator()],
    });
  }
```

SectorValidator is like the below

```
 private _sectorValidator(): ValidatorFn {
    return (control: AbstractControl): { [key: string]: any } | null => {
      const doesContainDemo = this.storeForm?.controls['doesContainDemo'].value;
      const storeSector = this.storeForm?.controls['sectorId'].value;
      if (doesContainDemo === true && !storeSector) {
        return { conditionalRequired: true };
      }
      return null;
    };
  }
```